# Scrolling to top of particular view causes NPE in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity and a fragment. I have two buttons in the activity and on click of both the buttons I am loading the same fragment. On Second button click I want to scroll to a textview's top position and the fragment has `NestedScrollView` as its parent.

I am using interface to differentiate between which button was clicked

```
interface HomeFragmentListener {
    fun shouldScrollToCampaign(scroll: Boolean)
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),... {

private var homeFragmentListener: HomeFragmentListener? = null

    fun setHomeFragmentListener(homeFragmentListener: HomeFragmentListener? ){
       this.homeFragmentListener = homeFragmentListener
    }

}
```

Following is my second button click code

```
loadFragment(HomeFragment())
homeFragmentListener?.shouldScrollToCampaign(true)
```

The fragment loading is as follows

```
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment?) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragment?.let { transaction.replace(R.id.fl_activity_main, it) }
        transaction.commit()
    }
```

My Fragment is as follows

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), HomeFragmentListener {

   override fun shouldScrollToCampaign(scroll: Boolean) {
        if (scroll) {
            nestedScrollView {
                nsv_fragment_home.scrollTo(
                    0,
                    textView.top
                )
            }
        }
    }

 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as MainActivity).setHomeFragmentListener(this)
..}

}
```

I am also calling Network Code when fragment is loaded

Comment: I think it's hard to know what happens with the provided code. Could you include the onClick codes, your Activity and Fragment layouts, and the Exception stack?

Comment: Can you publish the log which includes the NPE.

Comment: +2 for posting the log.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the set method for the listener and initialize listener when the fragment object is created, and cast to the interface.

try :

```
HomeFragment frg = HomeFragment()
homeFragmentListener = frg as HomeFragmentListener 
loadFragment(frg)
homeFragmentListener?.shouldScrollToCampaign(true)
```

Comment: Same Issue @AfinasEM

Comment: I am getting NPE for textView

Comment: Have you initialized textView before?

Comment: yes it is defined in my xml layout. I am also setting text to it programmatically and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method in fragment if it is already attached to the activity. On clicking on the second button in the activity, try this:

```
var homeFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fl_activity_main) as HomeFragment
homeFragment.scrolToTop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second button code, while calling `loadFragment(HomeFragment())`, your previous fragment is now destroyed. The reference of destroyed fragment is still stored in `homeFragmentListener`. So when you call the method implementing the interface, `textview` will be null. Even if you replace to right instance, there is 100% chance that it will still fail as the lifecycle would not have completed when you call `shouldScrollToCampaign`

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Move your buttons to fragment and redraw the views that needs to be updated.
2. If this is not possible or needs too much change, then pass a varible through bundle while creating the fragment instance and call your scrolling function after data is loaded.

   ```
   class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
       companion object {
           private const val MY_BOOLEAN = "my_boolean"

           fun newInstance(aBoolean: Boolean) = HomeFragment().apply {
               arguments = Bundle(1).apply {
                   putBoolean(MY_BOOLEAN, aBoolean)
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This is how you can instantiate your `HomeFragment` and in `onViewCreated` method check if `MY_BOOLEAN` is set to true and based on that scroll to view you want to scroll.